# Do these well-known results of complex analysis have names?

Tags: complex-analysis

In a proof I am writing, I wish to make CONCISE references to the following two well-known results in complex analysis (something like "by the XXX theorem" or "by the theorem of XXX").

1. (Weierstrass?) Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(z)$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ where every $f_{n}(z)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$. If  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}(z)$ converges uniformly, then the series is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$.
2. (Reconstruction of Analytic Functions?) Suppose $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are both analytic on $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$. If there exists a sequence, $z_{n}\rightarrow z_{0}\in D$ such that $g(z_{n})=f(z_{n})$ for all $n\geq 1$, then $g(z)=f(z)$ for all $z\in D$.

Do these theorems have names in complex analysis? The first one is credited to Weierstrass, but Weierstrass has so many theorems ...
The second one is related to "reconstruction", but does it have a proper name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is a particular case of the [Weierstrass uniform convergence theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Weierstrass_theorem#Uniformly_convergent_series_of_analytic_functions), which states that if $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly on any compact to a function $f$, then $f$ is analytic.
2. That's the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) (but you must add that $D$ is connected).